# Find the indefinite integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$
\int \frac{1-33\sec(x)}{\cos(x)-33}dx
$$
How do I simplify the fraction using trig identities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int\dfrac{1-33\sec x}{\cos x-33}dx&=\int\dfrac{\sec x(\cos x-33)}{\cos x-33}dx\\
&=\int\sec xdx\\
&=\int\dfrac{\sec x(\sec x+\tan x)}{\sec x+\tan x}dx\\
&=\int\dfrac{\sec^{2}x+\sec x\tan x}{\sec x+\tan x}dx\\
&=\int\dfrac{1}{u}du,~~~~u=\sec x+\tan x\\
&=\log|u|+C\\
&=\log|\sec x+\tan x|+C,
\end{align*}
where with $u=\sec x+\tan x$, $du=(\sec^{2}x+\tan^{2}x)dx$.